# Multiple CKEditor instance on same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor, wysiwyg

It's a weird problem, I have two ckeditor instance on same page, when I post the form, I'm always getting null value for the second one.

Could you help me to figure out my problem? Where am I wrong?

Here is the details,

### Create.cshtml

```
@model SevenNice.Models.Product

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "newproduct" }))
{
    // ... some other elements

    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description_0, new { @class = "ckeditor" })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description_1, new { @class = "ckeditor" })

    // ... some other elements
}
```

### Debuging steps

**1-**

[image]

**2-**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in CKEditor 4.2:
https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10689

It should be fixed in the next release. Meanwhile you can apply the patch locally or revert to an older version.